# Yii CDbMessageSource doesn't use de database

Tags: yii, translation

this is my config/main.php :

```
'components' => array(
    'messages' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbMessageSource',
    ),
```

and when i execute the command :
-Yiic messages c:/my...files/protected/messages/config.php

```
return array(
'sourcePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../..',
'messagePath'=>dirname(__FILE__),
'languages'=>array('fr','en'),
'fileTypes'=>array('php'),
'overwrite'=>true,
'exclude'=>array(
    '.git',
    '/assets',
    '/protected/migrations',
    '/protected/messages',
    '/protected/runtime',
    '/protected/extentions/gii',
    '/files',
),
```

);

the system save don't use de database but the files like if i use CMessageSource...

any idea ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify de in your array:

```
'languages'=>array('fr','en','de'),
```

Comment: -yes i did, and if i replace CdbMessageSource by CPhpMessageSource it's working but not with the bd